TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable while cleaning Data from excel file
df_dry.dropna(subset=['Quantity', 'Rate'])

I was trying to drop the row if any value from Quantity or Rate was missing, but I'm getting
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 1
----> 1 df_dry.dropna(subset=['Quantity', 'Rate'], axis = 0)

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

I tried using
def isFillled(cls,row,col,myMap):
        cls.isFilled = True

But it didn't work

Sometime earlier, you did df_dry.dropna = something.

It was probably a typo, but you've now corrupted that dataframe.

Don't use variables with the same name as functions. Assigning to cls.isFilled replaces the Classname.isFilled method with the True value.
